# DeckLink 4K Extreme capture videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, hdmi

I have **DeckLink 4K extreme** Capture card from Black Magic and i want to capture videos from HDMI input from my SET-Top-Box that it output format **yuv4:2:2 on HDMI.**

I set'up the bmdtool to capture frame and ffmpeg 2.6 to convert captured frames from yuv422 to mpg file (obtain video files - i want mpg or mp4)

I use this command for :

```
./bmdcapture -m 8 -V 3 -C 1 -F nut -f pipe:1 | ffmpeg -re -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv422p -i - -r 30 -f mpeg2videio -b:v 5M -y videoCaptured.mpg
```

Videos format : 1920x1080-30

But i always obtain a corrupted bmp file but when i use MediaExpress Black Magic SOtware it can display the result correctly whith capture file format as - AVI 10bit YUV.

So can you help me on that.

Comment: can you play the output with other programs? (as a note, you don't need -re certainly) also note ffmpeg has native decklink these days...

Comment: Yes i can display the stream on TV correctly but when i use bmdcapture even why vlc is show broken video stream. How can i use ffmpeg with the native decklink purpose. Any command suggestions.

Comment: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#decklink anyway my guess is you're recording it wrong somehow...

Comment: Thanks but when i do ffmpeg -f decklink -list_formats 1 -i 'Intensity Pro' for example . The output is  Unknown input format: 'decklink' !!

Comment: you need an ffmpeg compiled with decklink support...this is how I do it on windows, FWIW, GL! https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/blob/master/cross_compile_ffmpeg.sh#L1174

Answer (score 1):

Hey thank you very mutch.

The acquisition card worked with setting 422 color space on set-Top-Box and capture like this command.

./bmdcapture -m 8 -V 3 -C 1 -F nut -f pipe:1 | ffmpeg -re -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv422p -i - -r 30 -f mpeg2videio -b:v 5M -y videoCaptured.mpg


Thanks

Tomas